# Remove margin in css

Tags: html, css

[image: img example]

When I shrink the image in .showcase .slider img, to 70% I can't remove that margin that appears in the attached image, I don't know what I could do, any help? what I want is that that giant spacing is not shown, I tried with all the margin, padding and nothing .. Surely I will be applying some property wrong or I made a mistake in something, but I can not find the error. Or I will have wrong the width and height, please help. It must be a very silly mistake perhaps, but I can't find it.

```css
.showcase {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: #fff;
}

.showcase .slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showcase .slider ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400%;
  animation: change 20s infinite alternate linear;
}

.showcase .slider li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.showcase .slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<header class="showcase">
  <h2 class="title">X-TOUR</h2>
  <p class="parrafo">Ushuaia - Tierra del Fuego Antártida e Islas del Atrlántico Sur</p>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="news-cards">
  <div>
    <img src="img/parqueNacional.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>Parque Nacional</h3>
    <p>El Parque Nacional Tierra del Fuego, fue creado mediante la Ley 15554, promulgada el 30 de septiembre de 1960. Se ubica en la esquina suroeste de la isla de Tierra del Fuego, sobre el Canal Beagle y cercano a la ciudad de Ushuaia, conservando unas
      70.000 hectáreas de la Selva Patagónica que invitan a disfrutar de paseos en contacto con la naturaleza virgen. Los habitantes primitivos de esta zona fueron los aborígenes Yámanas, grupos de canoeros y mariscadores, que vivían en chozas en la zona
      de la Bahía de Lapataia. Hoy existen "concheros", círculos de acumulaciones de moluscos, que marcan los lugares de los antiguos asentamientos. https://ventaweb.apn.gob.ar/reserva/inicio?dp=09
    </p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/lagos.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>Lagos y más</h3>
    <p>Durante su estadía en Ushuaia, disfrute de una visita a lugares como: Laguna Esmeralda, Lago Escondido, Laguna Turquesa, Lago Fagnano, Cerro Castor, Tolhuin, y muchos más lugares.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/ushuaia.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>City Tour</h3>
    <p>Aprovecha al máximo tu visita a la ciudad más austral del mundo, terminando el día con un City Tour, para llevarte un recuerdo que no olvides nunca jamás.</p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's tough to identify the problem to see the attached image, can you please share your code into snipped?

Comment: The problem seems to be with `.news-cards` but you have not included any CSS related to `.news-cards`